# Can't find IIS manager on SQL Reporting Services 2008 machine to setup FQDN

Tags: iis, ssrs, ssrs-2008

I've got a machine that I inherited that runs SSRS 2008.  I can't seem to find IIS anywhere on this machine, yet it's serving up content over port 80.   I look under services and there is no WWW service running.

I need to configure a fully qualified domain name for this reporting instance and I am at a loss as to where to start.

Does SSRS 2008 run under its own web server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSRS 2008 does (by default) not rely on IIS. You can run them side-by-side if you wish, but it is no longer required.

To configure the URLs to access SSRS, you use the Reporting Services Configuration Tool - you probably want the "Advanced" configuration for Report Manager.

See the following link for detailed instructions on how to setup URLs in SSRS 2008.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447(v=SQL.100).aspx